# Listen for click or doubleclick of the widget

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

Is there a possibility to listen click or doubleclick event on the widget? I have followed the tutorial of creating the inline widget plugin and now I would like to listen for the click or doubleclick event on the widget from the following demo. https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/tutorials/implementing-an-inline-widget.html#demo

Answer (score 2):

if you want to listen to click event in the editor, you should use ClickObserver. However, it's not enabled by default, so you should add it.

The code for listening on click on the placeholder element will look like this:

```
import ClickObserver from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/observer/clickobserver';

const view = editor.editing.view;
const viewDocument = view.document;

view.addObserver( ClickObserver );

editor.listenTo( viewDocument, 'click', ( evt, data ) => {
    const modelElement = editor.editing.mapper.toModelElement( data.target);

    if ( modelElement.name == 'placeholder' ) {
        console.log( 'Placeholder has been clicked.' );
    }
} );
```

double click is not enabled by default, but you can create a custom click observer. You just need to extend a generic **DomEventObserver** class by a native DOM dblclick event.

Here's the code for that:

```
import DomEventObserver from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/observer/domeventobserver';

class DoubleClickObserver extends DomEventObserver {
    constructor( view ) {
        super( view );

        this.domEventType = 'dblclick';
    }

    onDomEvent( domEvent ) {
        this.fire( domEvent.type, domEvent );
    }
}
```

And then use it in the editor:

```
const view = editor.editing.view;
const viewDocument = view.document;

view.addObserver( DoubleClickObserver );
editor.listenTo( viewDocument, 'dblclick', () => {
    console.log( 'Double click fired.' );
} );
```

Hope this helps you!